# Why is my insert not working in php?

Tags: php, database, insert, mysqli

I have an insert statement I am querying to the DB.

```
$notes_sql = 'INSERT into notes SET
              order_id = "'.$_GET['order_id'].'",
              date_added = "'.$date_added.'",
              note_message = "'.$_SESSION['note_message'].'"';

$notes_result = $conn->query($notes_sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

I know the sql statement is correct, because when I try to echo it out and run that echo'd statement in phpMyadmin, it inserts it fine.

When I try to run the insert statement, I get the following error:

**INSERT command denied to user 'ideapale_amquery'@'localhost' for table 'notes'**

Line 74 is the line line of code that queries the statement.

I also know that I am correctly connecting to the DB through an included connection.php file, since I am using variables from that included file on the page I am working on.

I'm guessing I am somehow not correctly connecting to the DB, but I am not sure what it is. I copied the code for this page from another page that works fine, so I don't understand why it is not working.

Why is my insert not working in php?

***** UPDATE *****

This is my connection script:

```
function dbConnect($type) {
    if($type == 'query'){
        $user = 'ideapale_amquery';
        $pwd = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
    } else if($type == 'admin') {
        $user = 'ideapale_amadmin';
        $pwd = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
    } else {
        exit('Unrecognized connection type');   
    }

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pwd, 'ideapale_offorders') or die('Cannot open database');
return $conn;
}
```

This is how I am connecting to the connection script from the page I am on:

```
$conn = dbConnect('admin');
```

I am connecting to the DB using the admin privileges, so I don't understand why it thinks I want to use the 'amquery' username.

Comment: BTW, never, **ever**, do this: `order_id = "'.$_GET['order_id'].'"`. This screams SQL INJECTION ATTACK. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection Always, **always** sanitize user input, usually using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip deceze, but I will add the security features later on. I'm trying to get it up and running first

Comment: The problem is that "later" often never happens, for various reasons. Do it right from the beginning. :)

Comment: Security is something you need worry about from square one. Do not take it lightly, do not put it off. Otherwise, you *will* regret it. Someone will make sure of that.

Comment: if you use OOP, then use it => $conn->error

Comment: @codez - how would I use that?

Comment: @ zeckdude, ->error is a property of mysqli object. In your case just put in die: die($conn->error);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$notes_result = $conn->query($notes_sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

To get an updated error.

If the echoed SQL works fine you have to guess it's a connection or permissions issue. Are you doing an insert anywhere else?

Edit: So it's a permissions issue, run this:

```
GRANT INSERT PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ideapale_amquery'@'localhost'
```

However, if you don't believe you need to, try this first:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ideapale_amquery'@'localhost'
```

Comment: This is the updated error I am receiving: INSERT command denied to user 'ideapale_amquery'@'localhost' for table 'notes'

Comment: Haha timing or what - I just updated my answer to guess as much.

Comment: Put simply, you need to grant INSERT permissions to that user. See my updated answer (one moment).

Comment: So I guess I only have query priveleges on the user I selected, but I selected the admin user who has all priveleges for the whole DB.

Comment: I find that strange since I have been using the admin user everywhere on my site as well as here and it has full privileges, including SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for me to check the privileges on the user 'amquery' since that is not the user I am trying to connect to the DB with. For some reason, it is making me use that user. Please see my update so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Try echoing $user before your query. If it is amquery, try echoing type in dbConnect. If it is admin, try replacing your == with ===.

Comment: I checked the privileges and 'ideapale_amadmin' has SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE and 'ideapale_amquery' has just SELECT. But that is how I want it to be. That is why I chose to use the admin user in this case, but is selecting the query user for some reason

Comment: @zeckdude, please read my latest comment where I ask you to echo out at what stage it seelcts amquery.

Comment: I tried it again and the variable $user is not set for some reason. Also, when I added the additional '=', it didn't change anything.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was adding another dbConnect function call on an included file. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You claim to be connecting with the `ideapale_amadmin` user, but the error message `INSERT command denied to user 'ideapale_amquery'@'localhost' for table 'notes'` clearly shows that you are not. You are using the wrong MySQLi object (i.e. a connection you created earlier on in the script) or you are passing the wrong parameter to `dbConnect()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check and see what the error being returned is.

Change: `die(mysqli_error())`
To: `die(mysqli_error($conn))`